# pandas read json not working on Multiple index

Tags: json, python-2.7, pandas

**Hi i have the below data set in dataframe:**

```
app_id    | mob | qtr   |  amt_fin  | net_loss
------------------------------------------------
59101378  | 0   | 20143 | 32387.99  | 1.47
-----------------------------------------------
59101378  | 1   | 20143 | 32387.99  | 3.6
-----------------------------------------------
59101378  | 2   | 20143 | 32387.99  | 1.02
-----------------------------------------------
59101378  | 3   | 20143 | 32387.99  | 0.77
------------------------------------------------
59101378  | 4   | 20143 | 32387.99  | 0.77
-----------------------------------------------
59101500  | 0   | 20143 | 2500      | 1.088
-----------------------------------------------
59101500  | 1   | 20143 | 2500      | -0.13
-----------------------------------------------
59101500  | 2   | 20143 | 2500      | 0.43
-----------------------------------------------
59101500  | 3   | 20143 | 2500      | 0.45
```

**I need my json file like this:**

```
[app_id=59101378:{mob=0{qtr=20143,amt_fin=32387.9,net_loss=1.47},mob=1{qtr=20143,amt_fin=32387.9,net_loss=3.6},mob=2{qtr=20143,amt_fin=32387.9,net_loss=1.02},mob=3{qtr=20143,amt_fin=32387.9,net_loss=0.77},mob=4{qtr=20143,amt_fin=32387.9,net_loss=0.77}},app_id=59101500:{mob=0{qtr=20143,amt_fin=2500,net_loss=-.13},mob=1{qtr=20143,amt_fin=2500,net_loss=.43},mob=2{qtr=20143,amt_fin=2500,net_loss=.45}}]
```

it might have format issue, but the way indexing i am looking is same. Can you please let me know how i can achieve this in python,panda,json
i want my json file to index on app_id and then mob columns. but one single record for app_id

Comment: that isn't valid `json`.  I'm left trying to decipher if you want that exact pattern and thought it was `json` or if you want `json` and wasn't sure if what you presented is actually `json`.  If you want actual certified `json`, you **cannot** have what you asked for.

Answer (score 2):

This generates a correct json string in the orientation/order you're searching for:

```
df.to_json(orient='records')
```

Comment: OP, please notice this is correct `json` and almost certainly what you actually need.

Comment: that didn't helped.
I want the index to be on app_id and then mob.

Comment: the above syntax gave me mutiple {...} for same app_id,

Comment: you can also set_index and get orient='index'. You have to play with the arguments, but again, and as @piRSquared already mentioned to you, your issue is that you still don't know what qualified json you want so you would better work on this definition first